# What's the coefficient of OpenCV getDefaultPeopleDetector?

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram, svm, detection

I want to use the function of OpenCV of HOGDescriptor of getDefaultPeopleDetector(), here's my code:

```
HOGDescriptor defaultHog;
vector<float> svm_coefficients;
svm_coefficients = HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector();
```

But the thing I don't know is that what's the coorosponding coefficient to the block in HOG?

The vector "svm_coefficients" above is a 3781 dimension vector, and I have my own HOG feature extraction that extract 3780 features in an image, but what I don't konw is the relation between order of "svm_coefficients" and my feature

Answer (score 0):

The extra 1 coefficient at the end is the bias term in the SVM classifier, see [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9814).